# cordova-plugin-admob-free does not work with cordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: ionic-framework

My Ionic project infomation as following:

```
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4,
```

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^2.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="0.26.0">
        <variable name="ADMOB_APP_ID" value="xxx" />
</plugin>
```

However, when I tried to build, the following error occured

**"The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies."**

I have tried to add these dependencies to the root build.gradle, but it did not work:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

cordova-plugin-admob-free has dependency on play services SDK version 11.0.4

There is also another requirement that projects that use both Firebase and Play services SDKs of version 15.0.0 or less must run the same release versions. This therefore means that cordova-plugin-firebase must run FCM version 11.0.4

Do do this :-

1. ionic cordova platform rm YOUR_PLATFORM
2. ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
3. ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-admob-free
4. ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-admob-sdk (it's installed with cordova-plugin-admob-free)
5. ionic cordova platform add YOUR_PLATFORM
6. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=11.0.4 --variable ADMOB_APP_ID=YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID
7. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --variable FCM_VERSION=11.0.4